# Building and Plotting a discrete CDF

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, combinatorics, discrete

I'm trying to plot the CDF of a simple "nCr" experiment:

A box contains 4 screws and 6 nails. Two items are drawn at random without replacement. Let X be the number of nails drawn.

I built a piecewise function:

```
`F[x_] := \[Piecewise] {
 {12/90, 0 <= x <= 1},
 {60/90, 1 <= x <= 2},
 {1, x >= 2},
 {0, True}
  }`
```

which outputs an unexpected "shift":
[image]

which I can 'band-aid fix' by plotting F(x+1) in the 'DiscretePlot' function.

[image]

Am I thinking about the CDF function incorrectly? Is there another way to build and plot F?

Comment: Simply use: `Plot[F[x], {x, 0, 3}]` and do not use capital variable names, they are reserved for built in functions.

Comment: Have you already seen `EmpiricalDistribution[]`?